# how to only allow japanese characters in textbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm creating a website using PHP. is there anyway to only allow Japanese characters in the textbox?

I tried using IME-MODE: disabled in css but it is still accepting other language.

here is the code i used in html

```
<input type="text" style="-ms-image-mode: active; ime-mode: disabled;">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about japanese language. But I am using Indian (Hindi / devnagari) Language On my webpages To fill up forms with javascript. more info is available on http://www.vishalon.net/IndicResources/PramukhLib.aspx